# Webgl and dart changing data in vertex buffer every frame

Tags: dart, webgl

I have a very simple 'hello world' webgl app (the infamous triangle) and I decided I wanted to change the color of each vertices each frame to have a cool color show so I have this in my render method

```dart
if (tick % 5 == 0) {
    data[3] = rand.nextDouble();
    data[4] = rand.nextDouble();
    data[5] = rand.nextDouble();

    data[3 + 6] = rand.nextDouble();
    data[4 + 6] = rand.nextDouble();
    data[5 + 6] = rand.nextDouble();

    data[3 + 12] = rand.nextDouble();
    data[4 + 12] = rand.nextDouble();
    data[5 + 12] = rand.nextDouble();
}
```

where data is a Float32List containing 6 floats for 3 vertices.

I currently do this after the code of block above

```dart
gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferDataTyped(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, data, GL.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

which does the job but somehow I have a feeling that this is not the proper answer to my problem and might have performance repercussions.

Comment: Well, its fine for your triangle.
For more complex primitives you would want to utilize the fragmentshader. EDIT: You're talking about your "problem", what is your problem?

Comment: This would most likely be a simple rendering engine for a game with sprites only (4 vertices per sprite). I can imagine the xyz coordinate of my sprites would change quite often and there could be quite a bit of sprites on the screen at once

Comment: Now i get it, no you dont want to update your vertex buffer every frame to transform your geometry. Transformations such as translation, rotation and scaling are usually done by submitting a 4x4 matrix to the shader and doing the vertex transforms inside the vertex shader.

Comment: So for my sprites, I should have the 4 vertices and 6 indices (squares/rectangles) and apply my sprite transformations (position, rotation, etc.) on a uniform Matrix4 that is passed to the shader?

Comment: Yes, in addition to that you would only have *one* vertex buffer (the plane) and render it multiple times, binding different matrices and sprite textures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's nothing wrong with updating your vertices every frame if that's that you need to do for your app. For example these examples updates all vertices every frame

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/demos/google/nvidia-vertex-buffer-object/index.html

http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/google-io/2011/10000-objects-optimized.html

As for sprites as you mentioned in your comments, there are various ways to achieve sprites.

The most common way is *probably* to make a unit square quad with unit texture coordinates then use a 3x3 or 4x4 matrix adjust the vertices to render the size, place, and orientation you want and to use either another matrix or and offset and multiplier for the texture coordinates so you can translate and scale them to choose a particular sprite from a texture atlas.

I suspect though that a technique similar to the second sample above, updating vertices, will end up drawing more sprites than drawing one sprite at at time with a matrix for orientation and extra for texture coordinates.

For example, [here is a sample that draws one sprite per draw call](http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/lots-o-images/lots-o-images-draw-elements.html). On my machine I get around 8000 sprites at 50fps

[here is a sample that updates vertices every frame](http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/lots-o-images/lots-o-images-draw-elements.html) so it uses less draw calls. I get 72000 sprites at 50fps. That's nearly 9x the speed even though it's updating 72000x4 or 280000 vertices every frame.

Of course these samples are not doing the full work of a real sprite engine since they are always drawing the same sprite. If you used a texture atlas (so you needed up update texture coords) and you supported drawing sprites at different sizes, scales and orientations (so you needed to do vertex * matrix calculations in JavaScript) the timing might come out significantly different.

If I were you I'd start with the simplest method and abstract your usage so you can replace it later with something more optimized if you need it.